# requests.get.text error in python 3.6 really need some help here

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, spyder

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.104.com.tw/job/?jobno=5mjva&jobsource=joblist_b_relevance"
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = "utf-8"
print(r.text)
```

I want to reach the content in div ("class=content")(p)
but when I print the r.text out there's a big part disappear.
But I also found if I open a text file and write it in, it would be just right in the notebook

```
doc = open("file104.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
doc.write(r.text)
doc.close()
```

I guess it might be the encoding problem?  But it is still not working after I encoded in utf-8.

Sorry everbody!

===========================================================================

I finally found the problem which comes from the Ipython IDLE, everthing would be fine if I run the code in powershell, I should try this earlier....

But still wanna know why cause this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use `content.decode()`

```
    >>> import requests
    >>> url = "https://www.104.com.tw/job/?jobno=5mjva&jobsource=joblist_b_relevance"
    >>> r = requests.get(url)
    >>> TextInfo = r.content.decode('UTF-8')
    >>> print(TextInfo)
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>     <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>        <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>        <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="zh-tw"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />

.....
.....

the guts of the html code

.....
.....

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

    >>>
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help!

I run your code in spyder and azure jupyternotebook 3.6 after updating the bs4 and requests and.....still not work.

by the way! I found it would be correct if I write it into the text file and read it again

it's just so confusing!!

Comment: All I can say is that I ran that code, directly from the python prompt and got back the complete web page. I was unable to post all of it, as it was over 30,000 characters, many I note, where Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.104.com.tw/job/?jobno=5mjva&     
jobsource=joblist_b_relevance"
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
r=r.decode('utf-8')
print(r)
                         #OR
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"myhtml.html")
myhtml=open(myhtml.html,'rb')
print(myhtml)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice bro!
I'm using the anaconda + spyder environment and I update the "requests" to 2.19.1 and "bf4" to 4.6.3 and try you guys' code in spyder and azure jupyternotebook 3.6 still not work.